# subsetting dataframe R avoid for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, vectorization, subset

In a large dataframe (1 million+ rows), I am counting the number of elements (rows) that are within a particular range and satisfy a third criteria. I have 33 of those ranges and use a very slow for loop to get me the answer, no problem.

As speed is of massive concern, I would appreciate any help to get this to run faster. Can I get rid of the for loop and "vectorise" or any sort of "apply" solution?

Thanks in advance

Code:

```
N.data<-c(1:33)
Lower<-c(0,100000,125000,150000,175000,200000,225000,250000,275000,300000,325000,350000,375000,400000,425000,450000,475000,500000,550000,600000,650000,700000,750000,800000,850000,900000,950000,1000000,1100000,1200000,1300000,1400000,1500000)

Upper<-c(100000,125000,150000,175000,200000,225000,250000,275000,300000,325000,350000,375000,400000,425000,450000,475000,500000,550000,600000,650000,700000,750000,800000,850000,900000,950000,1000000,1100000,1200000,1300000,1400000,1500000, 5000000)

for (i in 1:(length(N.data))){
N.data[i]<-nrow(dataset[dataset$Z==c & dataset$X > Lower[i] & dataset$X < Upper[i],])
}
```

Comment: Could you post at least a subset of your dataframe (the one with 1million+ rows?)

Comment: `N.data<-c(1:33)`   .  `length(N.data)`  .  `[1] 33`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apply` functions are not VECTORIZED. They are merely more efficient implementations of a for loop. To achieve what you seek using vectorization, here is one approach.

```
# Create a Dummy Dataset and Breaks
dataset = data.frame(
  X = rpois(100, 10),
  Z = rpois(100, 20)
)
breaks = seq(0, max(dataset$Z), length = 5)

# Add Column with Breaks
dataset = transform(dataset, Z2 = cut(Z, breaks, labels = FALSE))


# Use Aggregate to compute length for each value of Z2
c = 10
aggregate(Z ~ Z2, data = dataset, length, subset = (X == c))
```

This should be more efficient that using `mapply`, as it is completely vectorized.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I can certainly see this is a more efficient implementation. Whereas the above-mentioned suggestion gives me zero values for "empty" ranges, yours simply omits. How I can change your last line of code to return 0 for empty ranges. Thanks in advance

Comment: No need for an answer here, found a solution myself using a simple ifelse statement.

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient approach:

```
# first logical index (vector)
idx1 <- dataset$Z == c

# second logical index (matrix)
idx2 <- mapply(function(l, u) dataset$X > l & dataset$X < u, Lower, Upper)

# combine both indices and count number of rows
N.data <- colSums(idx1 & idx2)
```